# Angular - change the main file of a dependency

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

How to change the main file of a particular dependency that we have added in the application.
I have installed an `npm` dependency which has 2 files `library.js` and `library.min.js` when running the below prod build:

`ng build --prod`

The build is having `library.js` file, but I want `library.min.js` file to be included in it.

How can I tell cli to take the minified library instead of the un-minified version?

Comment: Are they are not functionally equivalent? If they are then it does not matter and I doubt there would be any performance gain by feeding the minified version into the build.

Comment: As far as I can tell prod build minifies scripts anyway.

Comment: All scripts are minified in the build process so it doesn't matter if you use the min or not.